JOOQ custom data type converter/binding not being called when building dynamic queries with SelectWhereStep
I have a custom data type converter for java boolean field that will match a VARCHAR2 (6) column in Oracle, having stored in DB text of "false" or "true"
public class CustomBooleanConverter implements Converter<String, Boolean>{


    @Override
    public Boolean from(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return s.equals("true");
    }

    @Override
    public String to(Boolean aBoolean) {
        if (aBoolean == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return aBoolean.booleanValue() ? "true" : "false";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> fromType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public  Class<Boolean> toType() {
        return Boolean.class;
    }
}

And declare to be used in maven config like this:
 <forcedType>
      <userType>java.lang.Boolean</userType>
      <binding>com.jooq.config.CustomBooleanBinding</binding>                                                    
      <includeExpression>.*\.AMENDABLE</includeExpression>
 </forcedType>

And this would be the custom binding class:
public class CustomBooleanBinding  implements Binding<String, Boolean> {
    @Override
    public  Converter<String, Boolean> converter() {
        return new CustomBooleanConverter ();
    }

    @Override
    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<Boolean> bindingSQLContext) throws SQLException {
        String converted = converter().to(bindingSQLContext.value());
        if (bindingSQLContext.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED){
            if (converted == null) {
                bindingSQLContext.render().sql("NULL");
            } else {
                bindingSQLContext.render().sql("\'"+converted+"\'");
            }
        } else {
            bindingSQLContext.render().sql(bindingSQLContext.variable());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void register(BindingRegisterContext<Boolean> bindingRegisterContext) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<Boolean> bindingSetStatementContext) throws SQLException {
        String value = bindingSetStatementContext.convert(converter()).value();
        bindingSetStatementContext.statement().setString(bindingSetStatementContext.index(),
                value == null ? null : value);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<Boolean> bindingSetSQLOutputContext) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<Boolean> bindingGetResultSetContext) throws SQLException {
        bindingGetResultSetContext.convert(converter())
                .value(bindingGetResultSetContext.resultSet().getString(bindingGetResultSetContext.index()));
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<Boolean> bindingGetStatementContext) throws SQLException {
        bindingGetStatementContext.convert(converter());
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<Boolean> bindingGetSQLInputContext) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }
}


Files Generated by JOOQ looks fine:
    /**
     * The column <code>TABLEXX.AMENDABLE</code>.
     */
    public final TableField<TableXXRecord, Boolean> AMENDABLE = createField(DSL.name("AMENDABLE"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR(6), this, "", new CustomBooleanBinding());


But when building a dynamic query using SelectWhereStep, and adding a condition where a field is named AMENDABLE with boolean type and value true, the rendered SQL end up like this:

select alias_90892522.OTHER COLUMN,
             ......,
        alias_90892522.AMENDABLE 
from (
     select OTHER COLUMN,
             ......,
            AMENDABLE                       
      from tableXX
) alias_90892522
where
        (
   "alias_90892522"."OTHER COLUMN" = '0005698'
   and "alias_90892522"."AMENDABLE"      = 1
       )

Java code looks like:
SelectConditionStep subquery= select(tableXX.Other_column,tableXX.amendable ).from(tableXX);
Table<?> table = subquery.asTable;
SelectWhereStep<?> query = selectFrom(table);
query.where(table.field("OTHER_COLUM", String.class).equal("0005698"))
query.where(table.field("AMENDABLE,Boolean.class).equal(true)); 


It is done this way since query are built dinamically base on annotation for tables and columns.
I debugged the code  and the CustomBooleanBindingclass is never called.
Any clue what I am doing wrong?
JOOQ version is 3.14.9
I am expecting JOOQ to use the custom binding converter for a boolean type whenever any column is named "AMENDABLE" accordingly to the configuration implemented. But JOOQ instead uses the default boolean conversion of boolean to integer (true = 1) and I am expecting a conversion of boolean to string like ( true = "true").
that is making sql execution fail at runtime since the column is VARCHARD but JOOQ uses a NUMBER value
** I made some test if I change the flow and add the where condition in the inner query, the custom binding is called and it works, any clue why?
select alias_90892522.OTHER COLUMN,
             ......,
        alias_90892522.AMENDABLE 
from (
     select OTHER COLUMN,
             ......,
            AMENDABLE                       
      from tableXX
      where tableXX.AMENDABLE = 'true'
) alias_90892522
where
        (
   "alias_90892522"."OTHER COLUMN" = '0005698'
       )


Can you please provide a complete (and preferably minimal) reproducer that helps reproduce the problem? E.g. what is subquery (and is it necessary to reproduce the problem)? What does getFilteringCondition() do exactly? Also, what jOOQ version is this?

Hi @LukasEder I have updated the question with your required information and provided more clear code example. Also I made it work by hardcoding the flow and adding the where condition in the inner query, but I need to make it work with the condition in the upper query . Can you please have a look?

I had a simliar problem.
jOOQ Query Critera and forcedType converters
While I can't necessarily explain the technical aspects of the jOOQ internals, it seems that simple forced types with a converter work just fine for reading and writing values, but to use a converted value in a WHERE clause, you need to use binding instead of a simple converter.
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-binding/
<forcedType>
    <userType>com.example.MyDataType</userType>
    <binding>com.exampe.MyDataTypeBinding</binding>
    <includeExpression>
       my_table\.my_column
    </includeExpression>
</forcedType>

The binding implementation can make use of your existing Converter, but you need to do some extra work to render the appropriate SQL for your data type.
In my case, I wrote an abstract binding implementation for using a SMALLINT column to represent an enum.
abstract class AbstractSmallintEnumBinding<T> implements Binding<Short, T> {

  @Override
  public void sql(BindingSQLContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
    Short converted = converter().to(ctx.value());

    if (ctx.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED) {
      if (converted == null) {
        ctx.render().sql("NULL");
      } else {
        ctx.render().sql(String.valueOf(converted));
      }
    } else {
      ctx.render().sql(ctx.variable());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void register(BindingRegisterContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.SMALLINT);
  }

  @Override
  public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
    Short value = converter().to(ctx.value());
    if (value == null) {
      ctx.statement().setNull(ctx.index(), Types.SMALLINT);
    } else {
      ctx.statement().setInt(ctx.index(), value);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
  }

  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
    Short value = ctx.resultSet().getShort(ctx.index());
    if (ctx.resultSet().wasNull()) {
      value = null;
    }
    ctx.value(converter().from(value));
  }

  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
    ctx.value(converter().from(ctx.statement().getShort(ctx.index())));
  }

  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<T> ctx) throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
  }

}

Subclasses simply use extends AbstractSmallintEnumBinding<MyEnumType> and implement the conveter() method to provide an appropriate Converter.

"but to use a converted value in a WHERE clause, you need to use binding instead of a simple converter." that's not really true. Your case (from your linked question) was a different one. You didn't want the default binding for LOCALDATETIME (the T type) to apply in your case. Here, the default binding for VARCHAR (again, the T type) should apply, but somehow doesn't.

You did generate code and attached a binding to your generated code:
public final TableField<TableXXRecord, Boolean> AMENDABLE = 
    createField(DSL.name("AMENDABLE"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR(6), this, "", 
        new CustomBooleanBinding());

But then, you didn't use this exact column reference, but instead created dereferenced a coerced column:
query.where(table.field("AMENDABLE",Boolean.class).equal(true)); 

See the Javadoc on Fields.field(String, Class):

Get a field known to this type by unqualified name coerced to type using Field.coerce(Class), or null if no field is known to this type by this name.

Instead, use the original column reference to dereference the field using Fields.field(Field<T>)
query.where(table.field(THE_TABLE.AMENDABLE).equal(true)); 

Side-note
It's not necessary to do Field<Boolean>.equal(true). Just write this, instead:
query.where(table.field(THE_TABLE.AMENDABLE)); 

